# Quarkus Dev Services: What port do they run on?

Tags: quarkus, microprofile

I'm running keycloak as a dev service and I'm aware that I could configure a fixed port using `quarkus.keycloak.devservices.port`. However for this question, let's assume I use a system-assigned port.

**Question:** Now how do I (programmatically, with the means of Quarkus) find out, what port the dev service is running on?

I tried injecting this config value, however this results in an error when I don't specify it myself:

```java
@ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.keycloak.devservices.port")
String devServicePort;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that `quarkus.keycloak.devservices.port` is "fixed at build time". However injecting the following property works:

```java
@ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url")
String oidcUrl;
```

This gives me `http://localhost:52333/auth/realms/quarkus`, so I can then extract the port from it.

This answer is specific to keycloak - but other dev services have similar properties.